# distinguish Local and Global variable:

Tags: python, python-3.x

In this program:

```
num = 1
def fun1(num):
    print(num)
```

Does the variable `num` function as both a `global` and a `local variable` here? Because `num` is now a parameter, does that make it a variable local to `fun1()`?

Comment: It's a global var

Comment: There are two variables with the name num in this script.  The one in fun1 is local and doesn't last very long.  The global one survives until the end of the script.  To check this add the lines `fun1(2)` and `print(num)` to the end and see what happens.